# Weyl Group Requirements

Tags: lie-algebras

A Weyl group $W$ for a finite dimensional Lie algebra with root system $\Phi$ must be finite and a subgroup of the symmetric group on $k = |\Phi|$ elements. Are there any further conditions $W$ must satisfy?

Specifically, what finite groups can be realised as Weyl groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Weyl groups must satisfy further conditions. Recall that *all* finite groups arise as subgroups of the symmetric group $S_n$ for some $n$. For Weyl groups, the possibilities are much more restricted. We have the Weyl groups of type $A_n,B_n,C_n,D_n$, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143919/how-to-deduce-the-weyl-group-of-type-d?rq=1), and the exceptional types, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26760/what-are-the-weyl-group-of-type-e-8-f-4-g-2?rq=1). The Weyl groups of the classical Lie algebras are given by $S_n$ and semidirect products of $S_n$ with $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2^{n-1}$.